# applying sorting function in r for every four rows returns dataframe sorted but without extended selection, other columns are not sorted accordingly

Tags: r, sorting

I need every four rows to be sorted by the 4th column, separately from the next four rows, made a function :

```r
for (i in seq(1,nrow(data_frame), by=4)) { 

    data_frame[i:(i+3),4] <- sort(data_frame[i:(i+3),4], decreasing=TRUE) }
```

problem is only the 4th column gets sorted but the corresponding rows are maintained.

from

```
x y z userID
-1 1 2 5      1
-2 1 1 2      2
-3 0 0 5      5
-6 1 2 5      3

-4 1 1 2      6
-5 0 0 5      4
-4 1 1 2      1
-5 0 0 5      5
```

to -

```
x y z userID
-1 1 2 5      5
-2 1 1 2      3
-3 0 0 5      2
-6 1 2 5      1

-4 1 1 2      6
-5 0 0 5      5
-4 1 1 2      4
-5 0 0 5      1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `%/%` to create a grouping column with `%/%` and use that to `sort` the 'userID'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    group_by(grp = (row_number()-1) %/% 4 + 1) %>% 
    #or use
    #group_by(grp = cumsum(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), length.out = n()))) %>%
    mutate(userID = sort(userID, decreasing = TRUE))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   grp [2]
#      x     y     z userID   grp
#  <int> <int> <int>  <int> <dbl>
#1     1     2     5      5     1
#2     1     1     2      3     1
#3     0     0     5      2     1
#4     1     2     5      1     1
#5     1     1     2      6     2
#6     0     0     5      5     2
#7     1     1     2      4     2
#8     0     0     5      1     2
```

---

Or using `base R` with `ave`

```
with(df1, ave(userID, (seq_along(userID)-1) %/% 4 + 1, 
         FUN = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)))
#[1] 5 3 2 1 6 5 4 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), y = c(2L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), z = c(5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
5L), userID = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can `split` every 4 rows, `order` the fourth column and return the updated dataframe back.

```
df[] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, gl(nrow(df)/4, 4)), 
                  function(p) p[order(p[[4]], decreasing = TRUE), ]))

df
#  x y z userID
#1 0 0 5      5
#2 1 2 5      3
#3 1 1 2      2
#4 1 2 5      1
#5 1 1 2      6
#6 0 0 5      5
#7 0 0 5      4
#8 1 1 2      1
```

---

`tidyverse` approach using the same logic would be

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_split(gl(n()/4, 4), keep = FALSE) %>%
  map_dfr(. %>% arrange(desc(userID)))
```